Concave transformation and effect on function arguments
Consider $g(x)$ as an increasing concave function such that the following equation holds:
$p.g(a) + (1 - p).g(b) = p.g(A - k1) + (1 - p).g(B - k1)$
where $a$, $b$, $A$, $B$ are non-negative real numbers, $A ≥ a$, $B ≥ b$ and $0≤p≤1$.
If $f(x)$ is also an increasing concave function such that the following equation holds:
$p.f(g(a)) + (1 - p).f(g(b)) = p.f(g(A - k2)) + (1 - p).f(g(B - k2))$,
and $a$, $b$, $A$, $B$, $p$ remain unchanged, for what properties of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ can I conclude that $k1>k2$?

Hi, may you introduce the whole context of your work ? Especially your attempts, what are $k_1$ and $k_2$, and furthermore use Math Mod for your equation, basically two dollars around your math expression (one left and one right) or if you prefer big center expression (two left, two right of your expression). Thanks in advance. You may also find more answer to a well written post.

Thanks! I'll try Math Mod. As for the context: I am trying to model two risk-averse individuals (hence the increasing, concave functions to represent their utility functions). I am representing the utility function of the more risk-averse individual as a concave transformation of the other individual's utility function. Both are indifferent between two lotteries, (a, b; p, 1-p) or (A-k, B-k; p, 1-p), where k is variable (representing willingness-to-pay). I'm trying to see if there are specific properties of the utility functions that lead to higher/lower k.

Nice, put it now in your question (using Edit) so that you may get upvote and several answers !
